# CamFind java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add CamFind to my android application. here is my code to request image.

Code from Activity

```
try {
            HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("https://camfind.p.mashape.com/image_requests")
                    .header("X-Mashape-Key", "5Bjknd4AL0mshPTXoeE0oZGyTuRFp1zzpYEjsnWlO4mJju8hjV")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .field("focus[x]", "480")
                    .field("focus[y]", "640")
                    .field("image_request[altitude]", "27.912109375")
                    .field("image_request[language]", "en")
                    .field("image_request[latitude]", "35.8714220766008")
                    .field("image_request[locale]", "en_US")
                    .field("image_request[longitude]", "14.3583203002251")
                    .field("image_request[remote_image_url]", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/Mashape_logo.png")
                    .asJson();
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

my gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ovextech.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.3.20'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.2'


compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.2'
    compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3'
    compile 'org.json:json:20090211'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:4.3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.1'

}
```

I am getting following error on my Log

```
10-20 16:02:43.073  31716-31716/com.example.ovextech.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ovextech.myapplication, PID: 31716
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.refresh(Options.java:45)
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:34)
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.prepareRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:154)
            at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:131)
            at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
            at com.example.ovextech.myapplication.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you

**EDIT**
on line 32 is `.asJson();`

Comment: can you post line 32 of **MyActivity** class?

Comment: @hrskrs I have already edited my question, anyway its `.asJson();`

Comment: Have you tried restarting your IDE?

Comment: @PedroOliveira I have restarted it like 10 times. Thats the first thing I do when I get problem  like these ;)

Comment: have u check this https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/issues/35 ?